# Checking for an object being null in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I am writing my code in Java where I am creating an object and and accessing it in two different threads. My first `thread1` thread calls some public methods on this object at runtime.

```
final Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myObj.pubFunc1();
        myObj.puFunc2();
        myObj.pubFunc3();
    }
};
```

I have another thread `thread2` which might release this object and set it to `null`like:

```
final Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myObj.release();
        myObj = null;
    }
};
```

My question is if I should put check for `null` around each statement in my `thread1` like this?

```
final Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(myObj != null) {
                myObj.pubFunc1();
            }
            if(myObj != null) {
                myObj.pubFunc2();
            }
            if(myObj != null) {
                myObj.pubFunc3();
            }
        }
    };
```

OR only one check around all the statements is enough? The basic question that might originate from this is there is a lock around the object on which we have made a null check? How to handle this situation. What design pattern should I use to handle this situation.

**NOTE**: I do not want the three statements to be necessarily executed and I even do no want that the three statements form an atomic unit. I just want to perform an operation if the object I am performing the operation on is not null.

Comment: If the object can become null asynchronously, you must check for that, and it must also either be `volatile` or read and written only in `synchronized` blocks or methods. This is not a 'design pattern', it is just common sense, arising out of the JLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design your propose is flawed. Imagine this execution:

- `myObj = new MyObject();`
- Thread 2: `if (myObjec != null)` => all good, object is not null
- Thread 1: `myObj.release(); myObj = null;`
- Thread 2: `myObj.pubFunc1();` => Boom, NPE.

I think you only have 2 options:

- either you synchronize the accesses to `myObj` to make the if/pubFunc calls atomic
- or you save a local copy of the object - this may or may not be acceptable depending on your use case:

  ```
  public void run() {
    MyObject localObj = myObj;
    if (localObj != null { //NOTE: myObj may have been released
      localObj.pubFunc1();
      localObj.puFunc2();
      localObj.pubFunc3();
    }
  }
  ```

Note: I assume that you are aware of visibility issues and that `myObj` is properly published/synchronized.

Comment: I understand the meaning of an object being synchronized. What exactly do you mean by 'published'. Also, I assume that when you say 'visibility issues', these are related to private, public, protected and package level visibilities right?

Comment: @Swapnil no I meant visibility across threads. For example I suppose that either `myObj` is fully created before the threads start or it is volatile. And I also assumed that the various methods (pubFunc1 etc.) are thread safe.

Comment: So what I understand till now is that you propose to have the `null` check and all the three function call inside a synchronizedmy(Obj) (which would need to be surrounded by a null check also). And when you say that the methods are thread safe, you mean they have a keyword `synchronized` with their declarations right?

Comment: That's a bit simplistic and what you describe may or may not work. Thread safety and synchronization is all about the details so it's hard to say based on a high level description.