# Why assigning instance variable to local variable?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

This is something I see in Spring Boot code for example (in the `catch` block with `webServer` variable):

```
@Override
public final void refresh() throws BeansException, IllegalStateException {
    try {
        super.refresh();
    }

    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        WebServer webServer = this.webServer;
        if (webServer != null) {
            webServer.stop();
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Why not just doing `this.webServer.stop()`?

What is the purpose of local variable `webServer`?

Comment: If `webServer` is `null` it will throw an NPE.

Comment: you could check directly if this.webServer != null without creating new local variable webServer

Comment: @mohammedkhan you reach that point only after checking that `this.webserver` is not null anyway

Comment: @f1sh it does, guess what happens if between the null check the webServer field is set to null by another thread, you get an NPE, even if you did the null check.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary local variable webServer assignment and use the following directly:
 if (this.webServer != null) {
            this.webServer.stop();
        }// You don't even need to use this here

Comment: A field can be changed between two reads, by code you’re not seeing, the local variable can not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main purpose of the assignment is to avoid producing a `NullPointerException` when the `this.webServer` is set to `null` by a concurrent thread after the null-check and before the `webServer.stop()` call.

That is, without a local variable:

1. your thread: `this.webServer != null` -> true
2. another thread: `this.webServer = null`
3. your thread: `this.webServer.stop()` -> possibly results in `NullPointerException` (depending on visibility of change in step 2, this might not always happen; a race condition).

In other forms of code, assigning a field to a local variable can also have performance benefits compared to repeatedly referencing a field.

Answer (score 3):

If null-check would be done on the instance variable another thread could potentially nullify `this.webServer` after it was checked for null but before `webServer.stop();` is called. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459507/3879455) describes this behavior well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a multiple threaded environment, the same variable might have different value for threads. In such cases, if code env is not synchronised you'll get an NPE.

If you want to use `this.webServer.stop()`, make sure your read and write on this variable is synchronized at each place, otherwise use local variables as suggested.